# a tpl file does not work when adding jquery even with literal tags

Tags: php, jquery, smarty, prestashop

I have added a jquery script to tpl file and it won't work even with the literal tags
what's WRONG ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
{literal}
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{jQuery.validator.setDefaults(
{debug: true,success: "valid"});
$( "#PayformRIP" ).validate({rules: {
rip: "required",
rip2: {
  equalTo: "#rip"
}}});

$( "#dialogForUser" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        title: "receive your money",
        width: 500,
        height:300
});


$( "#link" ).click(function() {
    var dialogWidth = $(this).attr('dialogWidth');
    var dialogHeight = $(this).attr('dialogHeight');

    $( "#dialogForUser" ).dialog( "option", "width", dialogWidth );
    $( "#dialogForUser" ).dialog( "option", "height", dialogHeight );
    $( "#dialogForUser" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});
var rip = $('<div />').html('</br><form id="PayformRIP" method="post" action="" >RIP de votre compte:<input type="text" required="true" name="rip" class="input" ><p id="titre" >RIP de votre compte:</p><input type="text" required="true" id="rip2" name="rip2" class="input" ><input type="submit" id="ripbutton" name="ripbutton" ></form>');
var paypal = $('<div />').html('</br><form id="PayformPAL" method="post" action="" >Email Paypal:<input type="email" required="true" name="paypal" class="input" ></br>Email Paypal:<input type="email" required="true" name="paypal" class="input" ><input type="submit" name="paybutton" id="paybutton"   ></form>');rip.id = 'rip';paypal.id = 'rip';$('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(
function(){


    if ($(this).val() == 'paypal') {

        // appends the 'appended' element to the 'body' tag
         $(rip).remove();
        $(paypal).appendTo("#dialogForUser");
    }
    else {

        // if it's the 'No' button removes the 'appended' element.
        $(paypal).remove();
        $(rip).appendTo("#dialogForUser");
    }
});


});
{/literal}
```

here is my code, I'm waiting for your propositions because I have tried a lot and no OK results.

Comment: You haven't forgot the closing `</script>` tag?

Comment: Are you actually including the jQuery library?

Comment: Krister Andersson : no I did not it's not shown here

Comment: Pekka : Yes I make sure every jquery library needed is included

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML? But I think it's simplier and better to create JS files and include it from tpl.

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean that you get an error? if yes, which one?

Comment: no I don't get any error !! everything is fine but there is no "jquery" effect

Comment: uzsolt : I include the JS files in an controller, because I'm using u know the MVC architecture... it's not the first time I include something in a controller to use it in tpl but this is the first time I use scripts inside the tpl file and I don't see other way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

Should be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
or
$(document).ready(function()
```

**EDIT**

You can learn more about this situation by searching for `jQuery no-conflict (wrapper)`.

Personally, the final correct answer, why it is done, as it is done, I can not provide,

The only thing I know, is, when you use `$(doc…`, you can not use in that scope other functions with `$` (dollar-sign). If you use `jQuery(document).ready(function()` without `$`, instead of using for instance `$(this).addClass()` you are to use `jQuery(this).addClass()`.

Comment: Thank you ! it worked can you explain to me what does it add?